# Java Excel API JXL - reading cell formated as time

Tags: java, android, excel, api

I'm using Java Excel API to read data from Excels sheets in my Android project. I have some columns formated as time like this:
[image: Time format]

At first I tried read this cell using that code:

```
String cellContent = cell.getContents();
```

But as result I got content without hours eg :59:59. After that I tried get this time as seconds. I noticed that when cell data is get as DateCell, Date contents object has negative timestamp. I did some trick and I found value of timestamp for 0:00:00. I set variable with this value as positive (2209161600000L). Now I just add this variable to negative timestamp from cell and devide result by 1000 (milliseconds in second). Everything is fine until 23:59:59. Values above have extra 24 h (24:00:00 is reading as 48:00:00). I saw that Excel keeps this values in different ways.

[image: 23:59:59 time cell value]
[image: 24:00:00 time cell value]

I can just subtract this 24h but it isnt elegant solution. I want to get content as #:##:## string (which I prefer) or as seconds. Is there any good solution for this issue?

Comment: Please submit your fix as an answer :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Java Excel API is not developed since 2010 so I change library to Apache POI. Time cell is returned as fraction of 24h.

```
double fractionOfDay = cell.getNumericCellValue();
long timeInSeconds = Math.round(numericValue * SECONDS_IN_DAY);
```

Now everything works fine.